# Тестирование кода в Travis CI

Tags: java, непрерывная-интеграция, travis

Мне нужно в системе тестирования Travis CI в файле конфигурации .travis.yml написать проверку кода для проекта написанном на языке java, система сборки maven. Что нужно написать в файле и если можно с объяснением. А лучше какой-то образец для java, не официальную документацию, в ней я ничего не понял. Спасибо

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно добавить CheckStyle плагин и настроить проверку кода на соответствие правилам.

```
<plugins>
    ...
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-checkstyle-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.17</version>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <id>validate</id>
                <phase>validate</phase>
                <configuration>
                    <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                    <consoleOutput>true</consoleOutput>
                    <failsOnError>true</failsOnError>
                    <linkXRef>false</linkXRef>
                </configuration>
                <goals>
                    <goal>check</goal>
                </goals>
            </execution>
        </executions>
        <configuration>
            <logViolationsToConsole>true</logViolationsToConsole>
            <checkstyleRules>
                <module name="Checker">
                    <!-- Checks for Size Violations.                    -->
                    <!-- See http://checkstyle.sf.net/config_sizes.html -->
                    <module name="FileLength">
                        <property name="max" value="3500" />
                        <property name="fileExtensions" value="java"/>
                    </module>

                    <!-- Checks for whitespace                               -->
                    <!-- See http://checkstyle.sf.net/config_whitespace.html -->
                    <module name="FileTabCharacter"/>

                    <module name="TreeWalker">
                        <module name="StaticVariableName"/>
                        <module name="TypeName">
                            <property name="format" value="^_?[A-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]*$"/>
                        </module>
                    </module>
                </module>
            </checkstyleRules>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
    ...
</plugins>
```

[Пример использования в Maven проекте](https://github.com/Vaysman/travis-ci-example)

Comment: нет, эта строчка есть само собой, мне нужно чтобы стиль написания кода тестировался travis

Comment: @МатвеевЕвгений я обновил ответ и пример проекта

Comment: Спасибо за помощь. все получилось!

Comment: @МатвеевЕвгений не забудте пометить ответ как принятый.

Comment: подскажите как это сделать?

Comment: @МатвеевЕвгений рядом с ответом есть кнопка принять. http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer